# Is it worth repairing a broken kit lens?

Tags: lens, repair

I dropped my camera while on holiday last summer. Thankfully, my camera wasn't damaged but the kit lens has lost the ability to autofocus and the UV filter and 58mm to 52mm filter step-down (I use it to attach a fisheye filter to the lens) I had on its end are stuck and won't come off.

I've replaced the lens with an 18-200 zoom lens so I don't especially need it. I was wondering if it was worth getting the lens looked at and possibly repaired?

I've heard many places will charge you £50 or so just to look at the lens and given the cost of the kit lens I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Can you add the exact lens type please?

Comment: I'm going to remove the canon tag, because this question seems generally interesting and we've got at least one good Nikon answer below that may be useful to someone else.

Comment: Exact lens was the Generic Canon 18-55mm that comes as standard with a Canon 500D

Comment: The 18-55mm kit lens has literally no value.  I doubt most people would even attempt to sell this, so you could probably find it for free among friends or fellow photographers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably not - even if the repair were to cost less than the value of the lens it sounds like you're getting on fine without the lens, and are probably ready to move on to a better lens.

The only reason you might repair it is to sell, but without a free estimate you're taking a risk that you will lose money through this.

My advice would be to write it off and put the money towards a more interesting lens, maybe a 50 f/1.8 as you already have a superzoom.

Comment: I've already got the 50mm f/1.8 I'm debating getting another prime as well.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a Nikon, you can try to sell it for parts. Some people buy trashed AF Nikkors to get the contact block - this can then be added to a old MF lens to "chip" it. I did this with my old 18-55.

[edit]: now I see the "Canon" tag. But the answer is still relevant to those whose trashed lenses are Nikkors.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your initial guess is correct. Very few of the kit lenses are worth much more than the repair cost, so unless it is in warranty, it's probably not worth it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest selling it for parts, using as a pen/pencil holder or doing anything creative.