# Dropped camera, now lens won't attach to body - How much for repairs?

Tags: lens, nikon, equipment-damage

I dropped my Nikon D3200. Camera still turns on, but the lens wont attach to the body. It looks like something at the bottom of the lens might be broken; not the actual lens, but a small black circle type of thing. Anybody has any idea how much something like that will cost to repair?

Comment: Can you post some pictures of your lens? Does the camera shoot pictures without the lens attached?

Comment: See also [Is it worth repairing a broken kit lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/is-it-worth-repairing-a-broken-kit-lens)

Comment: it says you need a lens to shoot.

Comment: @dermot You will have to put the camera in manual mode.

Comment: The linked question discusses the "worth it" aspect of your question and is more relevant I think. Lens repair usually isn't that expensive, but for consumer lenses, it's not normally worth it. You're better off looking at a new one, the drop may be more damage than the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to contact a Nikon service center about it and ask them for an estimate.  It's hard to tell what might actually be wrong without a more detailed explanation and possibly photos.  Even the Nikon service center might not be able to estimate it without actually having the camera in hand.  There is normally a ring that doesn't go all the way around the lens on Nikon lenses, so what you think is the problem might not even be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that your camera works. Shoot a few pictures without the lens and confirm that you get pictures. Better idea would be to borrow a lens from a friend or go to a local retailer. If you figure that your lens is broken but your camera is okay, you can [buy a new lens for 200 or less](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Lens%20Mount_Nikon&ci=274&N=4288584247%204261208195%204108103566). This means your max budget for repairs should not exceed 200. Then follow @AJ Henderson's answer and decide which way you want to go based on the cost.

Comment: hmm it says it needs a lens to shoot..

Comment: @dermot You will have to put the camera in manual mode.